# Why doesn't the surrounding div affect the interior contents?

Tags: html, css

I have a setup like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/zzjSC/3/ and I am wondering why the surrounding div with the 1px black border does not affect the contents.
My main goal is centering the whole mess which is what I was trying to do with the `div` and yet it doesn't seem to be doing anything.  Is there any clean way to center it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `margin:0 auto;` centering trick on a block level element like a div, you also have to give it a width. BTW, change your margin from `auto 0px` to `0 auto`. The way you have it you're giving the top and bottom a value of auto and left and right a value of 0px.

The following CSS (you may need to change the width) should do it.

```
.right-align {
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    width: 1036px;
}
```

Comment: okay great I got it to do what I wanted.  I am still curious though, do you know why the border here in the updated one still doesn't cover the whole block?  http://jsfiddle.net/zzjSC/4/

Comment: It's due to the floats. You can add `overflow:auto;` to your right-align class, but that may make a scrollbar appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try `position: absolute;` on `.right-align`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set inside text to center position, use this code in .head class:

```
text-align:center;
```

if you want to set inside element to center position set them `margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;`